# Does Red Hat Enterprise Linux version 5 and 6 get support? What are all the unsupported versions?

Tags: rhel

In my company we have following Redhat servers,

- Linux Redhat 5.9
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6
- Linux Redhat 32bit 6.5
- Oracle Enterprise Linux 5

Are these all supported versions of red hat?

What are the unsupported versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Life Cycle page](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata) has the end-of-life dates (product support is for 10 years from release):

- RHEL 5: maintenance support 2 (errata and high-priority bug fixes) ended on March 30, 2017, with end of extended life cycle support (product retirement) on November 30, 2020
- RHEL 6: maintenance support 1 (errata and some hardware support) ended May 10, 2017, with end of maintenance support 2 on November 30, 2020 and end of extended life-cycle support on June 30, 2024

The following releases are beyond their extended life-cycle:

- RHEL 3: no longer supported as of January 30, 2014
- RHEL 4: end of extended life cycle was on March 31, 2017, current extended life cycle phase is "ongoing"

If you have your RH login information, you can go to [the Production Life Cycle Checker page](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/update_policies/) to get information on all your registered products.

According to the [Oracle Linux 5 Extended Support PDF](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/linux/oracle-linux-5-extended-support-3662088.pdf), extended support began on June 26, 2017 and ends on June 26, 2020. Be aware that it will cost you, however:

> **Pricing**
>
> Extended Support is available for Oracle Linux 5 at the
>   following uplift rates:
>
> - Year 11 after product release: Premier Subscription fee plus 10%
> - Year 12 after product release: Premier Subscription fee plus 20%
> - Year 13 after product release: Premier Subscription fee plus 20%
>
> Oracle Linux 5 Extended Support, like Oracle Linux 6 and 7 Premier
>   Support, is included with any Oracle Cloud Infrastructure subscription

Read the EOL policies carefully to make sure you understand what Red Hat and Oracle are providing during end of life! I'd strongly recommend upgrading, replacing, or decommissioning your RH 5.x and Oracle 5 servers pretty soon.